# Edit a particular string in a file based on another file

Tags: for-loop, awk, sed

Hello I have a file called users. In that file i have a list of users for example

```
user1 user2 user3
```

Now i have another file called searches where there is a specific string called owner = user for example

```
owner = user1
random text 
random text
owner = user15
random text
random text
owner = user2
```

so is it possible to find all the users based on the users file and rename those users to user@domain.com ? for example

```
owner = user1@domain.com
random text 
random text
owner = user15 
random text
random text
owner = user2@domain.com
```

Currently what i am doing is the long manual process like below

```
awk '/owner = user1|owner = user2|owner = user3/{print $0 "@domain.com"; next}1' file
```

and it actually does work but for large files i have to spend a long time creating this command.

Comment: `and it actually does work but for large files i have to spend a long time creating this command` could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: sorry, what i was trying to say is i can use this awk command awk '/owner = user1|owner = user2|owner = user3/{print $0 "@domain.com"; next}1' file and get it done but i have around 50+ users so creating this command will take a long time. thats why i was wondering if there was a loop i can create so that it reads from a file the user name instead of me pasting it again and again.

Comment: Why do you even need a `users` file? Surely you can find all the lines in `searches` that start with `owner=` and add the domain without needing a `users` file?.

Comment: the reason is there are owner = some names that i dont need editing. thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ head users owners
==> users <==
user1 user2 user3

==> owners <==
owner = user1
random text 
random text
owner = user15
random text
random text
owner = user2
```

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \t]*=[ \t]*|[ \t]+"}
FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) seen[$i]; next}
/^owner[ \t]*=/ && $2 in seen{sub($2, $2 "@domain.com") } 1' users owners
```

Prints:

```
owner = user1@domain.com
random text 
random text
owner = user15
random text
random text
owner = user2@domain.com
```